# Proteus, некорректная симуляция работы семисегментного индикатора

Tags: proteus

Решил поупражняться в протеусе... Собрал схемку, но вот уперся в какую-то магию. Ничего не понимаю. По идее, индикатор работать не должен, так как транзисторы не получают ток на базу, а значит, что что у индикаторов нет выхода на землю! Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]